# Unix serialport program with qt crashes

Tags: c++, qt, unix, serial-port, qtserialport

I am developing a simple serialport application with qt. I have configured the ttyUSB0 and i managed to open the port. But when datareceived from serialport my application closes. This is my code, Can anybody have an idea that what is wrong with this code ?

Thanks in advance,

```
    #include "linkasunixserialport.h"

LinkasUnixSerialPort::LinkasUnixSerialPort()
{
    fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
       qDebug()<<"open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyO1\n";
       exit(1);
    }

    qDebug()<<"devttyUSB0 opened";

    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL,  O_ASYNC );

    tcgetattr(fd,&termAttr);
    cfsetispeed(&termAttr,B115200);
    cfsetospeed(&termAttr,B115200);
    termAttr.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    termAttr.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    termAttr.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    termAttr.c_cflag |= CS8;
    termAttr.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    termAttr.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
    termAttr.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    termAttr.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&termAttr);
    qDebug()<<"UART1 configured....\n";

    this->start();

}
int LinkasUnixSerialPort::bytes_available()
{
    int bytesQueued;
    if (::ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &bytesQueued) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    qDebug()<<bytesQueued;
    return bytesQueued;
}

void LinkasUnixSerialPort::run()
{
    char receive_data[2];
    forever
    {
        int bytes_read = bytes_available();
        if(bytes_read > -1)
        {
            int retVal = ::read(fd, receive_data, 1);
            if(retVal != -1)
            {
                emit dataReceived(QChar(receive_data[0]));
            }

        }
        else
        {
            this->msleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well did you try to use a debugger

Comment: yes. but it says "the gdb process exited unexpectedly" i am new to qt and ubuntu. I dont know what is that mean ?

Comment: Go to Projects>Run options>execution and uncheck ‘Run in Terminal’

Comment: it is already unchecked.

Comment: @thehilmisu: why don't you use QtSerialPort?

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe better to use Qt 5.1 SerialPort support for this use case:
See further information on [QSerialPort documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtserialport/qtserialport-index.html) with examples on Qt Project Homepage.